# How can I sign an rpm package using a smart card?

Tags: public-key-infrastructure, digital-signature, gnupg, smartcard

I have a smart card (not OpenPGP card), and I am preparing to sign an rpm using this card. After signing, I will get two files: `my.rpm.sig`, and `my_id.cer`.

How can I sign my rpm using these extra signature and certification file without GPG?

Comment: That depends entirely on what the smart card is.

Comment: It is a normal hardware certification for signing, encryption, and decryption. Use PKCS#11 standard and  RSA algorithm. Th .cer file could be converted to .pem file by OpenSSL.

I could verify signature by OpenSSL. But I don't know how to use it while signing and verifying RPM installation.

Answer (score 2):

Per https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50622163/rpm-signing-using-x-509-certificates[enter link description here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50622163/rpm-signing-using-x-509-certificates) there is no way to sign RPMs with x509 style signatures that will be checked by the standard tools for installing RPMS. If signing x509 style is the important part then your best bet is to distribute the two files alongside the rpm along with instructions to those who care on how to use them to verify the origin of the rpm.

If on the other hand your primary goal is to use the keys on your smartcard rather than avoiding gnupg then you should be able to use [gnupg-pkcs11](http://gnupg-pkcs11.sourceforge.net/) to enable gnupg to talk to your PKCS#11 token (assuming that is what you smart card is) and add a  PGP signature which can be automatically checked by the standard tools for managing rpms.

Going the other way (using a PGPcard as a PKCS#11 token) is supported by [Scute](https://www.scute.org/)